# Distributting power to pixel strings

Tags: power-supply, led

I have:

- 16 pixel strings (WS2811), 50 LEDs per string, 5V, 3A (total)
- Power supply: 5V, 70A

I want to connect strings in parallel. Obviously, I can't connect all strings into one output of the power supply, because I won't be able to tighten the screw. So I thought that I can use a screw terminal block [like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07CLX1VW5), but it is rated for 15A, and I need at least 48A. Also, the wire that connects the power supply with the terminal block needs to handle 48A, which is 8 AWG.

I have a feeling that I don't quite understand all those amperage ratings. How to distribute the power correctly?

Comment: 15A is per terminal.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, but one of the terminals needs to be connected to the power supply, which requires 48A in my setup.

Comment: If your terminal blocks are rated for 15A, then you can connect up to 5 of your 3A strings to a terminal block. If you derate things a little to give you some headroom and connect 4 strings per block, then you'll have 4 wires which you need to connect over to your power supply. Can your supply take 4 wires, or do you need another higher-current rated terminal block to group the 4 wires into one?

Comment: @brhans, My power supply has 3 pairs of output ([+][+][+], [-][-][-], G, N, L), so I guess I can connect 2 wires to one output and 2 wires to remaining 2 outputs. As for wires, since there will be max 15A, do I need AWG 14 wire?